# Numpy and Python: impossible to sum two arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have two arrays of same dimensions (n,1), I need to sum these two arrays element per element but it seems impossible to me.
This is my code:

```
a += b
```

I have also tried:

```
a = a + b
```

and

```
a = np.add(a,b,axis=1)
```

and also a for loop over every element.

The result is always the original a array, and I don't know why... It's driving me crazy...

Edit:
The are both numpy arrays

Edit2:
I'm using python 3.

Edit3:
Here are the repr() of the two arrays:

```
array([[  2.61126134e+08],
   [  2.37858792e+08],
   [  2.32792708e+08],
   ..., 
   [  2.92302961e+08],
   [  2.24309513e+08],
   [  1.83542358e+08]])

array([[  34.7],
   [  31.7],
   [  30.5],
   ..., 
   [ 140.8],
   [ 142.5],
   [ 146.3]])
```

By the way, there's no need to down vote my question is such a brutal way.

**EDIT:**
Apparently it was a faulty NumPy installation. Reinstalled and worked correctly.

Comment: is it possbile `b` is zero?

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: Please `print repr(a), repr(b)`.

Comment: What's their `dtypes`?  Show a few values.  For example if `a` is an int dtype, and `b` small floats, `a` might not change.

Comment: @Shai No, b is not zero.

Comment: My dtype question is relevant to the `a+=` expression, but not the a=a+b. But just for kicks what does `c=a+b` produce?

Answer (score 1):

I have created two arrays with dimension 3 by 1, and added as:

```
a = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])
b = np.array([[3],[4],[5]])

a = a + b
print(a)  # it depends upon python which you are using, I am using python 2.7
```

Comment: The are both numpy arrays

Answer (score 1):

If your arrays are python list then you need to convert them to numpy  `a=numpy.array(a)` and `b=numpy.array(b)`.

if your arrays are in different length then you should resize the smaller one.

suppose b is the smaller one:

`b.resize(a.shape)
print a+b`